# Trying to delete from Join and I know I have funky spacing and I know I have dup IMEI's

Tags: sql, in-subquery

```
DELETE dbo.bBoxDetail
FROM dbo.bBoxDetail AS BD
INNER JOIN dbo.bBoxHeader AS BH ON LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.bBoxDetailId)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(BH.bBoxId))
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.ESNs)) = (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(IMEI)) FROM dbo.tmpIMEI)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

`BD.ESNs` is `NVARCHAR(50)` and `IMEI` is `NVARCHAR(30)` I have duplicate `ESNs` and I want to delete all `ESNs` that match the `SELECT ... IMEI`

Comment: In order to format your code, you can highlight the block and use the `{}` from the editing toolbar.

Comment: See also [How Do I Format My Code Blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Pay attention to **Subquery returned more than 1 value** as this is the error, you are returning any number of rows from your subquery:

The correct SQL is below:

```
DELETE dbo.bBoxDetail
FROM dbo.bBoxDetail AS BD
INNER JOIN dbo.bBoxHeader AS BH ON LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.bBoxDetailId)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(BH.bBoxId))
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.ESNs)) = (SELECT TOP 1 LTRIM(RTRIM(IMEI)) FROM dbo.tmpIMEI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) operator in WHERE clause

```
DELETE dbo.bBoxDetail
FROM dbo.bBoxDetail AS BD INNER JOIN dbo.bBoxHeader AS BH ON LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.bBoxDetailId)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(BH.bBoxId))
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.ESNs)) IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(IMEI)) FROM dbo.tmpIMEI)
```

but preferred option is [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188336.aspx) operator

```
DELETE dbo.bBoxDetail
FROM dbo.bBoxDetail AS BD INNER JOIN dbo.bBoxHeader AS BH ON LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.bBoxDetailId)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(BH.bBoxId))
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.tmpIMEI
              WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(BD.ESNs)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(IMEI))
              )
```

Comment: Both of these queries only seem to delete one row. tmpIMEI has 500+ but I cannot get more than one hit if I convert this to a select.