# Do we need to execute Commit statement after Update in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have done some update to my record through SQL Server Manager.

As Update statement is not having explicit commit, I am trying to write it manually.

```
Update mytable
set status=0;
Commit;
```

I am getting message as Commit has no begin transaction

Comment: You should begin a Transaction before committing.

Comment: You should open a transaction. Inside it you should perform update then commit changes.

Comment: See how it works here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The SQL Server Management Studio has implicit commit turned on, so all statements that are executed are implicitly commited.

This might be a scary thing if you come from an Oracle background where the default is to not have commands commited automatically, but it's not that much of a problem.

If you still want to use ad-hoc transactions, you can always execute

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

within SSMS, and than the system waits for you to commit the data.

If you want to replicate the Oracle behaviour, and start an implicit transaction, whenever some DML/DDL is issued, you can set the SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS checkbox in

```
Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> ANSI
```

Comment: Hi @SWeko. very helpful, thx. Am i right to assume, that checkbox unchecked means that transactions are commited implicitly? Thats my (default) situation. Naming of that checkbox is weird, then. btw, related issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576649/safely-delete-rows-in-sqlserver-so-you-can-rollback-a-commit

Comment: If the checkbox is checked, then a `SELECT` statement, implicitly starts a transaction, that will need to be explicitly commited.

Answer (score 6):

Sql server unlike oracle does not need commits unless you are using transactions.
Immediatly after your update statement the table will be commited, don't use the commit command in this scenario.