# Update Database MFC C++ ODBC CRecordset

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc, odbc, sdi

I'm Developing a MFC application (SDI) to update, add and delete a table in the database called security. 
The problem is after updating one row in the table, the row is Updated ( i verified) then when I do another action (updating another row or deleting a row) the update is canceled. I really don't know if there is a problem with the CRecordset or the database itself.

```
//m_pSet is a an instance of a class based on CRecordSet:

m_pSet->Open();
m_pSet->Edit();
m_pSet->m_Security_Id = sec->SecurityId;
m_pSet->m_Security_Name = sec->SecurityName;
m_pSet->m_Security_Type_Id = sec->SecurityTypeStringToInt();
if (!m_pSet->Update())
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Record not updated; no field values were set."));
}
```

Comment: You need to commit

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences with `Oracle` and `SQL Server` there is a difference in the way `commit` statements happen.  The behavior you are seeing implies that the `Update` is not implicitly committed.

In `Oracle`, commits are an explicit statement and need to be conducted after you have carried out some transaction.

In `SQL Server`, commits are implicit by default and do not need to be carried out after transactions.

That being said, this other other [Stack Overflow Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026602/do-we-need-to-execute-commit-statement-after-update-in-sql-server) appears to have two methods of making commits explicit in SQL Server, meaning without the commit, you may lose your transaction.

The first being that you can use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` to have the database wait for a commit statement.  From what you have posted, it would seem this is not the case.

The other way to make `commit` statements explicit in SQL Server is by changing some settings on the databsae itself.  Based on your line of thought I would check the settings referred to in the post noted here and ensure that you did not make commits implicit.